# Xcode standalone watch only project file targets

Tags: watchkit

If I create a project:
watch > app
Then select the radio for "Watch only app"
I get a project with 2 targets:
"AppName" with a destination of iPhone
and "AppName Watch App"

For an application that will only be available for watch and runs independently of iPhone, why is the iPhone stub being produced?
Is it required?

I'm sure this was caused my app to be rejected yesterday, with the reason:
"The app has no app icon"

When I inspected the binary I submitted, sure enough the First "AppName.app" has no icon. But the "AppName.app" nested inside that .app file does have the icon.

There is only one asset catalogue produced in the Xcode project, for the "AppName Watch App" to which I provided the icon.

The generated Xcode project (repeatable) also produces this warning:
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Library/Application Support/MessagesApplicationStub/MessagesApplicationStub.xcassets warning build: Could not get trait set for device Watch6,18 with version 9.1"

Its related to messages application stub.

So:

Can and should I remove the iPhone target stub?
Or do I need to address the missing app icon, and that warning some other way.?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get past a very similar error (below) by reinstalling Xcode. I have no idea why it worked, but it's something to try as a last resort.

> None of the input catalogs contained a matching stickers icon set or
> app icon set named  "MessagesApplicationStub".